# Cómo obtener este dato de array?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando ahora obtener el `nombre_cuenta` y colocarlo en mi array solo que no lo puedo traer.

Código:

```
<?php
$data_rfcs = array();
$data_cuentas = array(
 array(
            "troncal" => 12,
            "RFC" => "ASE081010612",
            "nombre_cuenta" => "Abalon Servicios",
            "DIDS" => Array (
                        524421611010,
                        524421611011,
                        524421611012,
                        524421611018
                        )
        ),
array(
            "troncal" => 33,
            "RFC" => "ASE081010612",
            "nombre_cuenta" => "Abalon Servicios",
            "DIDS" => Array (
                             524423074993
                            )
        ),
        array(
            "troncal" => 33,
            "RFC" => "ASE0810106sdf",
            "nombre_cuenta" => "otro1",
            "DIDS" => Array (
                        353434534
                        )
        ),
    array(
            "troncal" => 21,
            "RFC" => "ASE0810sdfsdf",
            "nombre_cuenta" => "otro2",
            "DIDS" => Array (
                        34875634
                        )
        ));

foreach ($data_cuentas as $key => $value) {
    if( isset($data_rfcs[$value["RFC"]])){
        $data_rfcs[$value["RFC"]] = array_merge($value["DIDS"],$data_rfcs[$value["RFC"]]);  
    }
    else {
        $data_rfcs[$value["RFC"]] = array_merge($value["DIDS"]);        
    }
}
print_r($data_rfcs)."</br>";
```

Mi intento por obtener "nombre_cuenta"

```
foreach ($data_cuentas as $key => $value) {
    if( isset($data_rfcs[$value["RFC"]])){
        $data_rfcs[$value["RFC"]] = array_merge($value["DIDS"],$value["nombre_cuenta"],$data_rfcs[$value["RFC"]]);  
    }
    else {
        $data_rfcs[$value["RFC"]] = array_merge($value["DIDS"],$value["nombre_cuenta"]);        
    }
}
```

Error que me manda

```
Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\unificar.php on line 45
Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\unificar.php on line 45
Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\unificar.php on line 45
Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\unificar.php on line 45
Array ( [ASE081010612] => [ASE0810106sdf] => [ASE0810sdfsdf] => )
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado final que esperas obtener, me parece un código confuso y quizá se pueda simplificar.

Answer (score 0):

El error te está diciendo exactamente lo que ocurre, los argumentos de array_merge() deben ser arrays, pero  $value["nombre_cuenta"] es un string. 
Lo que debes hacer es agregar nombre_cuenta al array:

```
$data_rfcs[$value["RFC"]] = $value["nombre_cuenta"];
```